# GitHub Remove Data pack

Tags: github

I’m using lfs to pay $5. I deleted the repository to delete the payment, but it still looks like I’m using it. How can I stop paying in a situation that looks like a picture?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried clicking the 'Downgrade data plan' button?

Comment: same issue with me